# ListView: Edit and save SelectedItem with a Button only

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, save, selecteditem

I have a ListView that is bound on an ObservableCollection.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Name="CustomerListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentCustomer,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                 <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In the same View i have some TextBoxes which are meant to edit the CurrentCustomer. I also have a save button. If you click this button the modifications of the CurrentCustomer should be saved. If the button "cancel" is pressed the modifications should be discarded.

```
<TextBox Name="CustomerSalutationTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20px" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentCustomer.Salutation, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The Problem is, if i make some changes on the currentCusomer, they are taking effect immediately.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Please, post the question in English

Comment: I added english comments ;-)

Comment: Better delete the german text, as it confuses while reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to add in your ViewModel / the class you have a binding context to is to save what was previous in the Textfield.
And when you hit abort, u just overwrite your newValue with the old one.

I'm going to setup a small example.

```
  class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _customerLastName;
    private string _customerName;
    private string _initialCustomerName;
    private string _initialCustomerLastName;

    public string CustomerName {
      get { return this._customerName; }
      set {
        this._customerName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public string CustomerLastName {
      get { return this._customerLastName; }
      set {
        this._customerLastName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public ExampleViewModel(string customerName, string customerLastName) {
      this.CustomerName = customerName;
      this.CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
      this._initialCustomerName = customerName;
      this._initialCustomerLastName = customerLastName;
    }

    //example event handler for your abort button
    private void OnAbortButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args) {
      this.CustomerName = this._initialCustomerName; //set the initial name
      this.CustomerLastName = this._initialCustomerLastName; //set the initial lastName
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
      this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
```

**Alternative**

As you might load your data from a database/csv file/something else, you should know the original values. When pressing the cancel button, you could invoke a CancelButtonClicked event in your ViewModel and some other class which subscribed to the ViewModels event and knows the original Model could set the original values on that viewModel instance, or just exchange the ViewModel instance with the original one.

Have a look at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

```
  class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _customerLastName;
    private string _customerName;

    public event CancelButtonClicked CancelButtonClicked;

    public string CustomerName {
      get { return this._customerName; }
      set {
        this._customerName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public string CustomerLastName {
      get { return this._customerLastName; }
      set {
        this._customerLastName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public ExampleViewModel(string customerName, string customerLastName) {
      this.CustomerName = customerName;
      this.CustomerLastName = customerLastName;
    }

    private void OnAbortButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args) {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
      this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }

  internal delegate void CancelButtonClicked(object sender);

  public class SomeOtherClass {
    private ExampleViewModel _viewModel;

    public SomeOtherClass() {
      this._viewModel = new ExampleViewModel("foo", "bar");
      this._viewModel.CancelButtonClicked += ViewModelOnCancelButtonClicked;
    }

    private void ViewModelOnCancelButtonClicked(object sender) {
      ExampleViewModel vm = sender as ExampleViewModel;
      vm.CustomerName = "foo"; //set the initial values again
      vm.CustomerLastName = "bar";
    }
  }
```

**Alternative2**

You could also exchange the complete VM when the event of the cancel button is invoked to retreive its original state.

**Alternative3**

Everytime your SelectedItem changes, you could save the current state of it by creating a copy of it. When your CancelButton is pressed, you set the SelectedItem to the copy of your original viewModel.

You'd need a copy constructor or a copy method for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you :-) yeah with an example it will be easier for me to understand what you mean :-)

Comment: hmm, i think i have to explain my problem better i will update it :)

Comment: allready edited the answer trying to explain an alternative (and cleaner) way of solving the issue :) i`m creating another example

Answer (score 0):

I've found out another solution. In the code behind of the view i've added following:

```
void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression be = customerFirstNameTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    be.UpdateSource();
}
```

My textbox with UpdateSourceTrigger Explicit

```
<TextBox Name="customerFirstNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="20px" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentCustomer.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsCustomerTextEnabled}"/>
```

And my button

```
<Button Name="SaveButton" Click="saveButton_Click" Margin="5" Content="Save"/>
```